# Swift how to make the mapview cover status bar

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to get the map view to cover the whole screen.

I tried to use below code which worked for couple runs

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

but then without changes it would revert back to this below look

[image]

Is there any other solutions to achieve the map covering the whole screen ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the map view's topAnchor constraint equal to superview's topAnchor?. It seems you are constraint equal to safearea's topAnchor instead.

Comment: Thank you it worked just needed to anchor it to the view and these code is unnecessary to achieve this type of view `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: glad to help sir